# How can I make it read all my pages and not just one PDF.JS

Tags: node.js, express, pdf.js, pdf.js.express

Good night people, I tell you..
I am working in node and express and I am getting the following error
It turns out that my pdf at the moment has 3 pages, but it can vary. What I need to do is find a way to read the number of sheets that the PDF has, I'm using pdf.js.

So in summary:
So what I need to do is do something in such a way that if the pdf has 3 pages, read me the 3 pages, if it has 4, read me the 4 pages and so on, I was reading the information that is https://mozilla.github.io /pdf.js/examples/ but it doesn't really fix much. Here's a picture of what I've done.

doc.numpages It returns the number of sheets, but when I use it by passing it to it, in this case, as numPages is = 3, it reads only the 3rd sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only calling `await doc.getPage()` after counting all the pages, so you only ever get the last page.

I'd imagine you need to move the `getPage` and `getTextContent` calls into the `for` loop and save the results in a data structure like an array until you've read the whole PDF and are ready to return it. For example:

```js
function getAllPages(doc) {
  let pages = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < doc.numPages; i++) {
    let page = await doc.getPage(i);
    let pageContent = await page.getTextContent();
    pages.push(pageContent);
  }
  return pages;
}
```

(P.S. it's much easier to help if you paste code as text instead of sharing a screenshot)